# Add Imagebutton to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, imagebutton

I am trying to do a simple 'Delete Row' button in a DataGridView that I have, but the problem is that I would like it to be an ImageButton rather than a simple Button.

Currently I have it setup to be a ButtonColumn, but have seen no possibility for changing it from a simple button with text to a button with an image on it.

I know this is possible and hopefully relatively simple, but am unsure of how to go about doing it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I should clarify.
This is a standalone app in straight C#...I don't have access to the ASP form types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to just go for a clickable image as opposed to an ImageButton, there's a pretty simple solution.

Add a ImageColumn to your dgView, set its "NullValue" to be a red X or whatever you want it to be.  This will ensure that all of the rows will always have the X showing with no extra work.

After that, you're going to want to add a "CellContentClick" event to capture the user actually clicking on the X.

Inside the cellcontent click event, you can check if

```
//check if your clicking on a cell inside the imagecolumn column
if(e.ColumnIndex == this.colImageColumn.index && e.RowIndex > 0)
   //Delete Row e.RowIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:buttonfield ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif"  commandname="ibtnEdit"  HeaderText=" " />
```

Comment: Opps! I think it's asp.net. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DGV_ImageButtonCell.aspx) looks like it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

On event dataGridViewMain_CellContentClick write following code

```
  if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewMain.Columns["ImageColumn"].Index)
  {
  lblShowCellData.Text = dataGridViewMain.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CustomerName"].Value.ToString();
  // Do some thing else....
  }
```

download full source code at http://tablegridview.blogspot.in

Answer (score -1):

**You can use a Template Field in GridView. Just like this:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="imgBtnDelete_Click" ImageUrl="~/media/Delete.gif">
    </asp:ImageButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```